# CSS border not working entirely

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have a site with boxes (used in table-form) which get CSS to have borders.
In Chrome, the output is what I wanted.
But in IE, it's totally ruined (linked images on tinypic).
On Firefox I have about the same problem.
Here's my CSS:

```
table#homeblockscontainer td
{
    border: 6px solid #EEEEEE;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

So I have a table with this ID and table rows and table data's under that.

My wanted result is this: [Result on Chrome](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/2ezk1mf/5)

What I get in firefox: [Result on Firefox](http://nl.tinypic.com/r/23jsgp5/5)

If anyone knows why this is happening, plz help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the html?

Comment: better yet, put it into a fiddle for us. (jsfiddle.net, codepen.io)

Comment: do you have a css reset on your site? Something like `*{margin:0;padding:0}` to reset browser defaults

Comment: try adding overflow: hidden; to your css... I wonder if it's an overflow issue

Answer (score 0):

do you use [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)? If you don't this CSS styles might help you

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

and since you are developing grid like layout, I don't know whether you already have it now or not but adding `box-sizing` will ease your life.

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: The css you suggested sadly didn't change the problem I have.
I actually have no idea what this box-sizing does, but I'll look it up!
As for the normalize.css, I think it's too much work to change everything to that...
thanks for responding though!